# JSON output differs between gcc and MSVC

Tags: c++, json, gcc, c++14, nlohmann-json

The below code snippet is using nlohmann-json library.
However the output differs between MSVC and GCC compilers (both compiled using `-std=c++14`).

[MSVC](https://godbolt.org/z/TGhGjrY5e) outputs:

```
{"test":[]}
```

[gcc](https://godbolt.org/z/hdx1c1qj7) outputs:

```
{"test":[[]]}
```

Code snippet:

```
#include "nlohmann/json.hpp"
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    nlohmann::json output;
    output["test"] = { nlohmann::json::array() };
    std::cout << output.dump() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

The line `output["test"] = { nlohmann::json::array() };` is triggering the difference in behavior. Removing the curly brackets around `nlohmann::json::array()` will align the behavior and always output `{"test":[]}`.
It seems the initializer list `{ json::array() }` is interpreted by GCC as: `json::array({ json::array() })` for some reason.

Could this be a potential bug in the json library, in GCC/MSVC or is there another explanation?

Comment: You should not use brace initialzation. The library authors do not recommend this.
[Here](https://json.nlohmann.me/home/faq/#brace-initialization-yields-arrays) is an entry from their FAQ why.
I guess MSVC is just another compiler with a different behaviour.

Comment: @mkaes Thank you, I was not aware about this page - this does explains the difference in behavior! If you want to move this comment to be an answer, I will accept it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The nlohmann library has an already known issue with brace initialization and different compilers.
They mention this issue in the [FAQ](https://json.nlohmann.me/home/faq/#brace-initialization-yields-arrays).

The workaround the library authors propose is to avoid brace initialization.